# How can I get line numbers in stack traces (haskell)?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've tried just about every remotely relevant command line flag I can find, and while I've been able to get stack traces, nothing can just give me line numbers. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: Do you mean the old (and basically obsolete) debug-mode stacktracing, or the now preferred [`HasCallstack`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-Stack.html#t:HasCallStack) one?

Comment: `echo 'main = error "whoops"' >test.hs && ghc test && ./test` prints (in part) `error, called at test.hs:1:8 in main:Main`. No special flags or anything. So I guess you'd better share some instructions about how to reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, the profiler-based stack traces are *not* obsolete. They can be rather more detailed than `HasCallStack` traces; I think the main issue is that you don't really want to compile code with profiling for production.

Answer (score 1):

HasCallStack is the way to go:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import GHC.Stack
import GHC.Stack.Types

main :: HasCallStack => IO ()
main =  putStrLn ((\(PushCallStack _ loc _) -> show (srcLocStartLine loc)) callStack)
```

```
% ./main
7
```